# how to remove "define" menu when text is highlighted in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiwebview

I tried doing this:

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender 
{
   return NO;
}
```

but it still pops up the menu, I also want to keep the copy, I just want to remove "define", is this possible? To clarify I don't want to remove the ability of text selection, I just wanted to remove the "define" option in the UIMenuController

Comment: Why do you want to block the user's ability to define words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you perhaps returning YES in canPerformAction:withSender further up in the responder chain?

*Note that if your class returns NO for a command, another responder further up the responder chain may still return YES, enabling the command.*

Comment: This is where a java-like Final keyword would come in handy in Objective-C

Comment: Wrong. The responder chain works across different classes (UIView->UIViewController->UIWindow->UIApplication). A "final" keyword would not help here in any way.

Answer (score -1):

You need to subclass UIWebView, then

```
-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender 
{
//    XLOG(@"perform action %@ with sender %@.", NSStringFromSelector(action), sender);
    if ((action == @selector(cut:)) || (action == @selector(copy:)) || (action == @selector(select:)) ||
        (action == @selector(selectAll:)) || (action == @selector(paste:)) || (action == @selector(delete:)))
        return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: From Apple's docs: The UIWebView class should not be subclassed.